# C# DataGridView Incorrect Scrollbar Size Causing Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a `DataGridView` and add several rows to it in a `for` loop (~35 rows) while it's `Enabled` property is set to `false`. I have done this in the past (when `Enabled` is set to true) and the vertical scroll bar block would update to the appropriate size compared to the `DataGridView`'s viewing area and the number of items in the grid. Now, however, it appears but is the incorrect size.

After I re-enable the `DataGridView`, I select a row and "arrow-down" through the rows until the program throws an exception saying "Value should be within the range" and is referring to the scroll bar. Also, I discovered that if I sort any of the columns it will update the scroll bar block to the correct size. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have just had the same issue and solved it as follows:

DataGridView.SuspendLayout()

... do the adding of the rows

DataGridView.ResumeLayout( true );

Comment: +1 I can confirm that this workaround actually works

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced same issue.

You can either do as
1. First set the DataSource to NULL then provide the Datasource again.

Or

1. Use BindingList to DataBind the DataGridView.

(posted from mobile)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
I tried everything.
In the end I settled for a work around. When I allowed AllowUserToAddRow to True the scrolling started working correctly.

I opted to handle this new row in code rather than have the error and the incorrect scrollbar. Perhaps this helps someone.